# Asking for ideas: Incorporating a Redux CRA App into express backend SSR App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux

Hi I am new to React and have a general design question. I am developing an app that's kind of similar to scratch (scratch.mit.edu), with a highly interactive program that enables user to create a project, drag and drop and connect to play with modules. And also it should has a multiple pages dashboard for user login, profile, home, and also open up a project and go to the interactive program to edit.

Currently our progress are quite separated: the 'playable' program is build by create-react-app and has redux to control the state; and the multiple pages dashboard is build on express server with server side rendering.

Now I need to incorporate the two parts and asking for some suggestions: Is it a good idea to switch the CRA project to ssr and route it in the express project? Does that create issues with Redux? Or is it better to just keep them seperated and they will be running on two different servers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common scenario and generally can be solved by one of three ways.

- Use separates servers
- Use a proxy
- Have express server run dynamic routes **and** use `express.static` for pre-built React bundle

The third option is usually the easiest, say if you are deploying to a PaaS environment like Heroku.

This article - [How to deploy a create-react-app with an Express backend to Heroku](https://medium.com/@chloechong.us/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app-with-an-express-backend-to-heroku-32decfee6d18) - details the steps needed for the third option.